# Include graphics from subfolders

Tags: graphics, paths

I have this structure:

- mainfolder/main.tex
- mainfolder/frontmatter/front.tex
- mainfolder/frontmatter/images/logo.jpg

Now i **include** front.tex in main.tex, but i can't view the logo.
PS: I want specify graphicspath in front.tex and include all in main.tex

Comment: `\expandafter\def\csname graphics@path\endcsname{{/frontmatter/images}}` (from memory, I'm not sure it works).

Comment: @Manuel no need for expandafter, csname, or @, just use `\graphicspath`

Comment: You have not really given any useful informaton. What do you mean by "can not view the logo" do you get an error from tex, if so what. What argument do you give `\includegraphics` (the path should be relative to your main file, not the included file.)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ahm, `\graphicspath` is the one that sets the path (I mixed with `\input@path` :D).